# example where quicksort crushes

Tags: quicksort

I know  that quicksort is not stable  method, namely for  equal elements,  maybe    member of array  will not be placed at correct position, I need  example of array (in which elements are  repeated several times) quicksort does not work (need for example three way of partitioning method). I could not be able to find such  example of array in  internet and could you help me?

sure I can use other kind of  sorting methods for this problem (like heap sort ,merge sort, etc), but my attitude is to know in real world example, what kind of data contains risk for quicksort, because as  know  it is one most  useful method and is used often

Comment: Not stable doesn't mean it produces incorrect output. If implemented correctly, the output will always be sorted. There are no inputs that would generate non-sorted output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quicksort shouldn't crash no matter what array it is given.

When a sorting algorithm is called 'stable' or 'not stable', it does not refer to safety of the algorithm or whether or not it crashes. It is related to maintaining relative order of elements that have the same key.

As a brief example, if you have:

[9, 5, 7, 5, 1]

Then a 'stable' sorting algorithm should guarantee that in the sorted array the first 5 is still placed before the second 5. Even though for this trivial example there is no difference, there are examples in which it makes a difference, such as when sorting a table based on one column (you want the other columns to stay in the same order as before).

See more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_sort#Stability

Comment: i am  asking exactly this,if for example array contains 1 3 3 3 3 4 2 5 3 6 7 8,result would be sorted?if yes then what kind of stability is in mind?

Comment: and solution of this problem is three way partitioning?

Comment: The result will always be sorted. Stability is about whether the 3s stay in the same order after the array is sorted. Some algorithms cannot guarantee this, others can. That is stability. Look at the Wikipedia link and it will make sense